# Extracting companies and all their properties from Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to extract all companies from a specific stock index, e.g. Dow Jones together with all their properties from Wikidata. Take IBM for example, then the output should somehow look like this:

```
instance of -> software company...
part of -> Dow Jones Industrial Average
...
```

I hope it is clear what kind of output I am looking for.

Comment: Can you describe what approaches you've tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial

Comment: `select * {
?company wdt:P361 wd:Q180816
  }` - the rest is up to you ... (hint: you're not the first asking for all properties of an item/entity in Wikidata here, just use the search function) - then combine both queries